# Using the Vsphere api how can I get the "powered on" state history of VM's?

Tags: vmware, vsphere

How can I get the history of a VM's power state? Questions like "when was the VM last powered on?"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `recentTask` property of a VM, it contains recent operations, including Power on/Power Off.